# Where is this LoginActivity retrieving phoneno. and password from?

Tags: java, android, mysql

The LoginActivity.java is the first thing that gets run after I open the android app and a login screen is seen asking for phonenumber and password which it retrieves from a database. I have a mysql database related to this project running in my computer but how do I find exactly from where in the database the app is retrieving the phoneno. and password from?

**LoginActivity.java**

```
package com.example.ankit.mrestro.Controller;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.baidu.android.pushservice.PushConstants;
import com.baidu.android.pushservice.PushManager;
import com.squareup.otto.Subscribe;
import com.example.ankit.mrestro.Bus.BusProvider;
import com.example.ankit.mrestro.Bus.LoginEvent;
import com.example.ankit.mrestro.Bus.LoginSuccessEvent;
import com.example.ankit.mrestro.Bus.PushRegisterEvent;
import com.example.ankit.mrestro.R;
import com.example.ankit.mrestro.model.LoginResult;
import com.example.ankit.mrestro.services.DataService;
import com.example.ankit.mrestro.services.RESTrepository;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_ID = "cust_id";
    public static final String PREF_TOKEN = "accessToken";
    public static final String SHARED_PREF_DB_NAME = "loginResult";
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public static Intent createIntent(Context c) {
        return new Intent(c, LoginActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DataService.init();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        /**
         * Check either we are already logged in
         */
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_DB_NAME, 0);
        if (sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_TOKEN, "").length() != 0) {
            RESTrepository.setToken(sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_TOKEN, ""));
            RESTrepository.setUser_id(sharedPreferences.getInt(PREF_ACCOUNT_ID, 0));
            goToMainActivity();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        PushManager.startWork(getApplicationContext(), PushConstants.LOGIN_TYPE_API_KEY,
                "hwfeocSIPlgKTasIuARPREnS");
        //SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("pushService",0);
        //String userId=preferences.getString("user_id","no data");
        //Toast.makeText(this,"user id is:"+userId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Button loginButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                String phoneno=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
                String password=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString();

                //      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"login..."+phoneno+"..."+password,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.show();
                BusProvider.get().post(new LoginEvent(phoneno,password));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        BusProvider.get().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        BusProvider.get().unregister(this);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onLoginSuccessEvent(LoginSuccessEvent loginSuccessEvent){
        progressDialog.hide();
        LoginResult result=loginSuccessEvent.getResult();
        if (result != null) {
            //  Toast.makeText(this,result.getCust_id()+result.getCust_name()+result.getCust_access_token(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Toast.makeText(this,"Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            preferences.edit().putString(PREF_TOKEN,result.getCust_access_token()).commit();
            preferences.edit().putInt(PREF_ACCOUNT_ID,result.getCust_id()).commit();
            SharedPreferences pushPreferences=this.getSharedPreferences("pushService",0);
            BusProvider.get().post(new PushRegisterEvent
                    (result.getCust_id(),result.getCust_access_token(),pushPreferences.getString("user_id","")));
            goToMainActivity();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to login, please retry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void goToMainActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Login Activity  your on button click your are getting the the phone number and password of your sending it to the server and `onLoginSuccessEvent` you are getting your response and save it to the `sharePreferences`

Comment: But it keeps saying "Unable to login, please try again!" I can't seem to login to the app. What am I not getting here?

Comment: did you store your phonenumber and password in sql , in other words did you sign  up ?

Comment: basically on server your user name and password will compared to the user name and password you send by putting it in editText

Comment: yes i did store them in sql, and i'm logged in to phpmyadmin i.e. the sql database if that's what you're asking.

Comment: your result is returning null                                                                         LoginResult result=loginSuccessEvent.getResult(); it mean you not getting any thing from service

Comment: How do i fix that?